# Mathematical representation of a signal

Tags: notation

I'm using a very simple signal to test some statistics. Let the period be $p = 2\pi$, I have two signal

$SW = sawtooth(3 p)$

and

$SQ = square(1.5 p)$

I do some manipulation in those two signal, the first manipulation is

$SW = (SW + 1)/2$

this put my sawtooth limited in $[0,1]$, and

$SQ = (-SQ + 1)/2$

This inverts the square wave and also "normalizes" it betweeen $[0, 1]$.

My final signal is

$SIGNAL = 20*(SQ*SW) + 10*SQ$

The final product is a single saw in middle of period, with amplitude 20 and translated up 10 , giving the limits $[10,30)$ in signal support and $0$ elsewhere. Something like

[image]

Then I add some heavy random noise (20% of signal amplitude)

$NOISE = RANDOM(MAX(SIGNAL)*.2)$

My final signal is the original signal plus the noise.

$FINALSIGNAL = SINAL + NOISE$

My questions are

1. How to matematically be more consistent with my signal notation (instead to use that computer science like description)?
2. Is there any signal operations that can be done instead those algebraic ones or those are valid in signals?

Comment: I don't know about "consistent" but in EE work I have always found that using the delta function and integration to be the most efficacious in dealing with these types of problems.  Usually, I then resort to Laplace transforms.  Another thing is that adding "natural" noise requires taking some delicate steps. The whole thing is simple once some basic ideas are learned.  I can't find a good reference right now but I could reproduce the process.  Do you know Laplace xforms and delta functions?  Without these, the answer would be quite long.